# Php переменная ломает код если задано значение включающее AND

Tags: php, запрос, redbeanphp, variable

есть redbeanphp и такой код фильтрации данных (думаю с логикой понятно будет как работает):

// тут если передаются дополнительные фильтры - пишем их в поиск redbeanphp

```
if( $_POST['filter_area'] != '' ){ $f_area_s = 'AND id_area= ?'; $f_area_d = $_POST['filter_area'].","; }
```

// делаем поиск по базе и фильтруем, если есть фильтры выше (вывод только не удаленных)

```
$magazin = R::findAll('magazin ', 'id_city= ? '.$f_area_s.' AND deleted= ?', [$city_id, $f_area_d 0]);
```

вот мол не нравится такой вариант :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как быть ? пробовал разные варианты, видимо тот самый не подобрал. прошу помочь :) фильтров много будет, хочу добавлять вариации которые выбирают в запрос по шаблону выше..

что пишет на выходе

```
<b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'
```

Comment: Если по синтаксису, то у вас не хватает запятой между  $f_area_d и 0. А если по логике, то лучше создайте два массива. По условиям вроде этого if добавляете в первый выражения типа 'id_area=?', а во второй значения для вопросов, т.е. $_POST['filter_area']. Запрос строите `implode(' AND ', первый_массив)`, а второй массив это фактически последний параметр R::findAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить так:

```
$w = ['id_city=?', 'deleted=?'];
$v = [$city_id, 0];
if(isset($_POST['filter_area']) and $_POST['filter_area'] != '' ) {
    $w[] = 'id_area= ?'; $v[] = $_POST['filter_area'];
}
// Другие условия, добавляющие строки запросов в первый массив и подставляемые параметры во второй
$magazin = R::findAll('magazin ', implode(' AND ', $w), $v)
```

Comment: я извиняюсь, а как этим способом искать состоит ли значение в диапазоне ?

например, приходят данные соритровки возраста от 20 до 30 лет, или зарплата  больше 2000$ - как такие условия добавить вашим способом ?

Comment: @Quotsu `$w[] = 'age between ? and ?'; $v[] = 20; $v[] = 30;`  `$w[] = 'salary > ?'; $v[] = 2000`. в принципе и подзапросы дописать можно. главное для всех ? во второй массив значения записать

Comment: благодарю! нужно отдохнуть, совсем не соображает голова уже :)

Comment: Пока вы мгновенно отвечаете - имею наглость еще вопрос :)

Допустим есть поле в бд наличия чего-либо в заведении такого вида:

a:2:{i:0;s:21:"Есть вайфай";i:1;s:38:"Есть летняя площадка";}

как вашим способом отфильтровать заведения с Вайфаем ? 
плюс вам в карму заранее :)

Comment: @Quotsu не хранить в БД такие странные строки, напоминающие php serialyze. Хотя бы json сделали для него хоть какие то функции в БД есть (хотя от БД зависит). А тут только `like '%"Есть вайфай"%'. вариант конечно, носколькими способами могли обозначить наличие wifi ...

Comment: это данные с чекбоксов - они стандартные, да пишется serialyze =\
спасибо за помощь! протестирую на свежую голову

Comment: благодарю, методы работают!

Comment: добрый, помню помогали с запросом - не подскажете как совместить в один такой :
$feedbacks = R::findLike( 'feedbacks', [ 'id' => $_SESSION['ids'], 'whom_type' => 'd', 'text LIKE %'.$_POST["wrd"].'%' ] );

$_SESSION['ids'] - массив id, $_POST["wrd"] - запрос для поиска

сейчас это выводит ошибку Identifier does not conform to RedBeanPHP security policies

RedBeanPHP\Finder->findLike('feedbacks', Array, '')

Comment: @Quotsu Ну это какая то ошибка самого readbean не SQL, так что я не знаю. Точнее вижу что в интернете пишут, что readbean это говорит когда в идентификаторе нестандартные символы. И что то мне подсказывает это из за процентов в `'text LIKE %'`. И я вообще не понимаю этой части массива, до этого у вас идет имя поля - значение, а тут как бы только само значение или имя (видимо redbean считает это именем)

Comment: у меня в созданных вопросах расписано. Я решил задачу getAll + convertToBeans